# Why doesn't xterm support double-sized characters when using Xft fonts?

Tags: fonts, xterm

Whenever I configure `xterm` to use *core X11 fonts*:

```
*.vt100.renderFont:             False
*.vt100.locale:                 False
*.vt100.font:                   -monotype-courier new-medium-r-normal--*-120-*-*-m-*-koi8-r
```

it renders [double-sized characters](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECDHL.html) properly:

[image]

But when I configure it to use client-side fonts:

```
*.vt100.renderFont:             True
*.vt100.faceName:               Courier New:antialias=false
*.vt100.faceSize:               12
*.vt100.utf8:                   1
*.vt100.utf8Fonts:              True
*.vt100.utf8Title:              True
```

it fails to render double-sized characters, which can be confirmed via the [`vttest`](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/) utility:

[image]

Both *PuTTY* (on *Windows*) and `konsole` **do** use client-side fonts and still render the double-sized text properly.

Have I mis-configured my `xterm`, or is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known limitation, which (see [changelog](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_350)) was addressed late in 2019.  Starting with patch #350, the ability to draw VT100-style double-sized characters is a feature compiled-in by default.  The configure [option](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/424295c8ec01c9238b63a8f664f0e17d53a7f99f/INSTALL#L155) summarizes it:

```
  --disable-doublechars   disable support for double-size chars

    Do not compile-in code that supports font-manipulation needed to
    implement vt100-style double-sized characters.
```

while the changelog for patch #349 is pertinent to this question:

> reorganize text-drawing to make it possible to investigate using Xft to implement VT100-style double-sized characters. While doing this, made a workaround for apparent Xft bug which loses its drawable state when switching from 132 to 80 columns.

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:boldMode) says (note the omission of *TrueType* fonts from the discussion):

```
           Although xterm attempts to derive a bold font for other
           font selections, the font server may not cooperate.  Since
           X11R6, bitmap fonts have been scaled.  The font server claims
           to provide the bold font that xterm requests, but the
           result is not always readable.  XFree86 introduced a feature
           which can be used to suppress the scaling.  In the X server's
           configuration file (e.g., “/etc/X11/XFree86” or
           “/etc/X11/xorg.conf”), you can add “:unscaled” to the end of
           the directory specification for the “misc” fonts, which
           comprise the fixed-pitch fonts that are used by xterm.  For
           example

               FontPath                 "/usr/lib/X11/fonts/misc/"

           would become

               FontPath                 "/usr/lib/X11/fonts/misc/:unscaled"

           Depending on your configuration, the font server may have its
           own configuration file.  The same “:unscaled” can be added to
           its configuration file at the end of the directory
           specification for “misc”.

           The bitmap scaling feature is also used by xterm to
           implement VT102 double-width and double-height characters.
```

Handling double-width/double-height characters using *TrueType* fonts is implemented differently, by drawing/clipping one character at a time with a font that's been double-sized.  Of course, with ***fontconfig***'s metrics (which often ignore the nominal bounding box), there is no guarantee that the result will look nice.

For what it's worth, PuTTY and konsole have their own problems with this test:

[image: PuTTY, same test but next page...]

[image: Konsole, likewise]

[image: XTerm, same test]

PuTTY doesn't handle the line-drawing part of the test, and Konsole's typically coming up with some odd window sizes.  Also, if you look closely, there are minor discrepancies in the alignment of the single- and double-width text ([*ymmv*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv)).

Comment: Thank you Thomas for such a detailed response. I have to remark that PuTTY line drawing issues can be mitigated by export'ing `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1` (for ncurses-based applications in UTF-8 locale).

Comment: ...but that doesn't apply to vttest -hth

Comment: Nope, it doesn’t. I assume because vttest doesn’t use ncurses =)

Comment: sure - ncurses is general (adapting to different types of terminals), but vttest is specific: vt100s never did UTF-8, since they came ~15 years before UTF-8 was thought of.